# C: int string accepting all values, but one?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I cannot find a similar problem on the internet.

I have a file with random int values. I want to save them in string.
I want to allocate a block of memory in the beginning and then, during the reading from the file, if the block is insufficient, to reallocate enough space.

```
ptr = (int*)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(int));
    while ((fscanf(fp, "%d", &num)) != EOF){

        switch (state){

        case 0:

            if (counter < SIZE){
                *(ptr + index) = num; 
                index++; 
            }                   
            else state = 1;

            break; 
        case 1:

            ptr = realloc(ptr, counter*sizeof(int));
            *(ptr + index) = num; 
            index++;                
            break;
        }

        counter++;

    }
```

The problem is, my code skips the SIZE-th integer. 
If I try to save the value like this:

```
else {
        *(ptr + index) = num;
        index++;
        state = 1;
     }
```

Then I get random negative values after the SIZE-th element?

Comment: Why are you making (what looks like) a state machine for this? Are you planning for more different states (and what would they represent)? As it stands: just put an `if(counter == SIZE)` with your array resizing code _before_ you put the value into the array and get rid of the whole `switch` construct.

Comment: Style: `*(ptr + index)` is often written as `ptr[index]`.    Also, `*(ptr + index) = num; index++`  ->  `ptr[index++] = num`.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to do just what you say, but my teacher don't like it and told me to do it this way, but now I mess up something

Comment: How are you getting back to `case 0`?  I see you are setting `state = 1` in `case 0:`, but I don't see a `state = 0` in `case 1:`.

Comment: well, once i am in case 1, I don't need to go back to case 0 (i am reading from a fixed file with integers)

Comment: You are using C.  There is no need (and its wrong) to cast the return of `[m][c][re]alloc()`.  And you should include enough code to ***[allow someone to compile it](http://sscce.org/)***.

Comment: The index and pointer have the same function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your switch state-machine is broken and it is really hard to tell the exact place. Here is clean version of what you seem trying to achieve:

```
size_t count = 0;
size_t size = 4; // any initial size > 0
int *ptr = malloc(size * sizeof(*ptr)); // assert(ptr != NULL);
int num;

while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &num) != EOF) {

    if (count >= size)
        ptr = realloc(ptr, (size *= 2) * sizeof(*ptr)); // assert(ptr != NULL);

    ptr[count++] = num;
}
```

Each iteration tracks `size` (capacity) or an array and `count` of items in it. If `count` got equal to `size`, it is time to resize and then do everything as usual. The factor of 2 is one of most efficient (you may use 1.5 for MB-sized arrays).

Or even without temporary `num`:

```
while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &ptr[count++]) != EOF)
    if (count >= size)
        ptr = realloc(ptr, (size *= 2) * sizeof(*ptr)); // assert(ptr != NULL);
```

Sidenotes:

- do not cast malloc();
- use sizeof() for names (lvalues) where possible, not for types;
- do not duplicate entities (index/counter).

**EDIT:** Okay, it seems that is one of "[X] using [Y]" quizzes.

```
// loop body
{
    switch (count >= size) {
        case 1:
            ptr = (int *)realloc(ptr, (size *= 2) * sizeof(*ptr));
            /* fall-through */
        case 0:
            ptr[count++] = num;
            break;
    }
}
```

All in all you're just a-nother brick in the wall...

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate you advices, and it works this (your) way, but I HAVE TO use switch state and HAVE TO cast malloc();

Comment: @S.F.R.PARTIZAN switch used; malloc casted. Good luck!

Comment: Yep, I have to. But why it is not working when I just add *(ptr + index)=num; 
index++; in the else statement?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Look, each iteration *reads* an integer from a file so that if you skip an assignment, the number is lost. You just can't end iteration without ptr[index] = num, because iterator cannot be rewound.

Comment: you are right, I am becoming just a-another brick :(

Comment: @S.F.R.PARTIZAN I think your question needs to be reformulated in abstract terms, because here we have both coding and algorithmic issues mixed together. If you have to use state machine, extract fscanf from loop condition and call only when needed, converting loop to for (;;) { ... }. There will be 2 states: "time to resize" and "time to parse" with break on EOF.

Answer (score 1):

In your original code, when counter == SIZE, you break and then increment counter to SIZE + 1 before saving the SIZE element. So, it is skipping the SIZE element.

In your attempt to fix the code, it looks like you are saving the SIZE-th integer to memory that hasn't been allocated yet?

Get rid of the switch; you can do everything you want with the if/else.

Comment: Yes, I did something familiar it with if else (and it was working perfectly) BUT my teacher said: NO, you must use switch and malloc (instead of calloc)

Comment: Too bad we can't fix your teacher. Hey, when you realloc for the first time, counter == SIZE. You want SIZE + 1.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're skipping the SIZE'th integer is because you break after changing the state.  You need to do something like this:

```
    case 0:

        if (counter < SIZE){
            *(ptr + index) = num; 
            index++;
            break;
        }                   
        else state = 1;

    case 1:

        ptr = realloc(ptr, counter*sizeof(int));
        *(ptr + index) = num; 
        index++;                
        break;
    }
```

Notice how there is no break after changing state to 1.  This will cause the code to "fall-through" to the next case statement.  Otherwise case 1 won't be executed until the next iteration of the while loop.

Honestly though you don't need a case statement.  You could simplify your code a lot by doing this inside your loop:

```
if(index >= SIZE){
    ptr = realloc(ptr, index*sizeof(int));
}
*(ptr + index) = num; 
index++;
```

There is no need for a case statement.  If you want to avoid reallocating so much you could reallocate a larger chunk of memory and test the counter against the size of how much memory you've allocated.

Comment: Thank you, but now I get the negative int's after SIZE-th like before, BUT the last value is there (500).

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of using the fallthrough method, but if you needed to do it I would recommend getting rid of `case 1:` altogether and make it `default: \* This will happen during a fallthrough from case 0: *\ `  Then get rid of the `else state = 1;` statement altogether.  That way if you haven't reached `EOF` in the `while()` loop, you won't just continually allocate more memory.  It's also a documented fallthrough so that its a little easier to find for the next guy when it becomes a problem.

Comment: @embedded_guy I agree with getting rid of the `else state = 1`. In fact I really think the whole switch statement is unnecessary, which is why I presented two different solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code is somewhat verbose but works.

**update**: My test was to short too run into the problem.  As others have pointed out already, if `counter==SIZE` the superfluous `break` prevents the item to be added to the array.

I've completed your code into the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 4

int
main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("in", "r");
    int *ptr = (int*)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(int));
    int num, counter=0, index=0, state=0;

    while ((fscanf(fp, "%d", &num)) != EOF) {
        switch (state) {
        case 0:
            if (counter < SIZE){
                *(ptr + index) = num;
                index++;
            }
            else state = 1;
            break; // this break causes the problem
        case 1:
            ptr = realloc(ptr, counter*sizeof(int));
            *(ptr + index) = num;
            index++;
            break;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    printf("%d items read\n", counter);
    return 0;
}
```

If I put the numbers 1 2 3 into the file "in", the program correctly prints "3 items read".  Did you spot that the results are stored in `ptr[0]` up to `ptr[counter-1]`, *i.e.* the last value is **not** in `ptr[count]`?

Some suggestions:

- I don't think the distinction between counter and index is necessary in your program.  They seem to be always the same.
- I don't believe the switch statement is required.  Just keep track of how long your array currently is, and whenever you run out of space call `realloc`.
- `malloc` and `realloc` can return `NULL` if the system runs out of memory.  It may be worth to explicitly check for this case.
- It is customary to increase the array size in steps larger than 1, so that you don't need so many (potentially slowish) calls to `realloc`.

Comment: ptr[0] up to ptr[counter-1] - yes, I did.

Comment: for the realloc and state- my teacher wants to be like this, I hate state machines

Comment: okay, but why when I just write *(ptr + index) = num; index++; in the else it does not work?